# How to get config from a EFISTUB kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, efi

I am working on getting normal Linux onto a x86 Android tablet. Only kernel I can find is `efilinux.efi` located inside the system’s ESP (`\EFI\Intel\efilinux.efi`). But I can’t get config through these three ways:

- `/proc/config.gz`
- `/boot/config-[whatever]`
- even not using `scripts/extract-ikconfig` from kernel tree gives me `extract-ikconfig: Cannot find kernel config.`

So are there other ways to get the config out? Or just no way to do that?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to get the full config out of an EFISTUB kernel.  However, some config can be retrieved from /sys/firware/efi

Comment: @fpmurphy1 inside `/sys/firmware/efi` i only get efivars, seems like pretty unrelated to the kernel itself.

Comment: There is absolutely no way of getting the config out of the kernel unless built with IKCONFIG